# How to use QgsRasterFileWriter to save and reproject raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, coordinate-system

I have to save georeferenced png images as GeoTiff and reproject them from different coordinate systems (UTMs ang Google) to given UTM. I want to do this with pyton code and tried to use QgsRasterFileWriter.

I face two problems here:

1. How to save file with 4 bands (transparency band)
2. How to reproject file at the same time

For now my code does the first thing and looks like this:

```
# Load Raster
fileName = myRaster.png
baseName = myRaster
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)

crsSrc =  rlayer.crs()  # may be any
crsDest =  QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)  # WGS84 or UTM Zone

renderer = rlayer.renderer()
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(baseName + '_TEST.tif')
file_writer.Mode(1)

file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, provider.xSize(), provider.ySize(), provider.extent(), provider.crs())
```

I tried with using QgsRasterProjector but never got it right.

Comment: see this pot [PyQGIS Reproject Raster - not reprojecting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223672/pyqgis-reproject-raster-not-reprojecting)

Answer (score 1):

Just use this command:

> gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:32643 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff "Input Raster with EPSG=32643" "Output Raster with EPSG=4326"

Comment: Using gdalwarp doesn't work properly with 4-bands png image. It reads only 3 bands.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the output extent in the coordinate system you are reprojecting the raster to. You can reproject your extent using the following code:

```
# Code for QQIS 3.xx - QgsCoordinateTransform is different in v 2.xx #
crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(rlayer.crs())
crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326) #epsg of target crs
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, QgsProject.instance())
projected_extent = xform.transformBoundingBox(provider.extent())
```

Then use this projected extent in the QgsRasterFileWriter.write_raster function:

```
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, provider.xSize(), provider.ySize(), projected_extent, provider.crs())
```

Comment: now you're writing to the same source CRS, but with the extents in the output CRS?.