# PyQGIS Reproject Raster - not reprojecting

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, coordinate-system

I'm writing a QGIS plugin that will reproject a raster.

I have all the pieces and it's writing a new raster with the new projection, but isn't reprojecting the underlying data.

The QGIS documentation says '[CRS to reproject to](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterFileWriter.html)' but I'm concerned that no reprojection is being done. I'd prefer not to use GDAL, but I'm now at the point where I've exhausted my options in the PyQGIS API, I think...

My code is below:

```
layer.setCrs(orig_crs)
tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(orig_crs, dest_crs)

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(out_file)
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
result = file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                                 provider.xSize(),
                                 provider.ySize(),
                                 tr.transform(provider.extent()),
                                 dest_crs)
```

Edit: I'm editing now and will add a bounty.

The question really is this: How can you use the built-in QGIS Python API functionality to transform a raster. Answers accepted for QGIS 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: Why not use gdal directly. This is what QGIS does for raster processing.

Comment: Hey @radouxju, I did do this and it works fine. I think the question remains, though, as it ought to be possible using QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

The QGIS documentation for **QgsCoordinateTransform** also [says](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateTransform.html) that 'transform' method is for **QgsPoint** or **QgsRectangle** objects; not for raster objects. However, I was able to get a result with your code but, it was totally weird probably for the former reason. My adapted code is:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
orig_crs = layer.crs()

dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32142)

tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(orig_crs, dest_crs)

out_file = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/reprojected_raster.tif'

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(out_file)
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
pipe.set(provider.clone())

result = file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                                 provider.xSize(),
                                 provider.xSize(),
                                 tr.transform(provider.extent()),
                                 dest_crs)
```

and I got next result:

[image]

Original raster is (791 rows x 1680 columns):

[image]

and reprojected raster by using **gdalwarp** command in next code:

```
import os

layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

source_path = " -of GTiff " + provider.dataSourceUri()
target_path = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/utah_dem_UthNorth2.tif"

CRS = layer.crs()
source_epsg = CRS.postgisSrid()
new_espg = 32142
target_epsg = " -t_srs EPSG:" + str(new_espg)

cmd = "gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:" + \
                        str(source_epsg) + \
                        target_epsg + \
                        source_path + \
                        " " + \
                        target_path

print cmd

os.system(cmd)
```

it was (practically original indistinguishable):

[image]

However, this raster has 800 rows x 1684 columns. So, if some possibility of reprojection exists with 'writeRaster' method, you shouldn't force it to have the same rows and columns that original raster.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might be complicating things by including the transform command, but I was testing with transforming the extents to see if that made a difference (it doesn't).

I think that the writeraster method is NOT transforming, just defining the projection as the new projection, which is bad.

Comment: looking at the "glitchy" version, I see that `provider.xSize()` is used for both axes, which might not work if the x and y cell sizes differ. Is that a typo? That might explain the weird results.

Comment: Hi @StevenKay. The cells of the raster don't get shifted, so I doubt that's the cause (my test data was a simple and small, 200 m change).

Comment: When using writeRaster in 3.10, the result looks fine but is not projected properly for me (using the UI Save As... results in a good projection however). Also note since 3.8 writeRaster is asking for 'transformContext'

Comment: Is there anyway of making the os.system(cmd) quiet? i.e. avoiding the cmd window to open and just running the function in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `QgsRasterProjector` ([see doc](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterProjector.html)) which has a `setCrs()` method to "set source and destination CRS".
The `QgsRasterProjector` is accessible by applying the `projector()` method on a `QgsRasterPipe` object.